# Trying to setup MQTT connection from Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm trying to setup the MQTT connection from my android app. Its AWS iot connection where I want to subscribe and publish to topics.
The same connection is setup already via web widget using following code -

```
 mqttClient = AWSIoTData.device({
      protocol: 'wss',
      clientId: conversationId+uuidV4(), // uniqueId added for persistent connection per tab in browser
      debug: false,
      maximumReconnectTimeMs: 18000,
      qos: 1,
      host: IoTCreds.IoTHostEndPoint,
      region: IoTCreds.region,
      accessKeyId: IoTCreds.accessKeyId,
      secretKey: IoTCreds.secretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: IoTCreds.SessionToken
    })
```

Now I am trying to setup similar connection from android app but getting this error-

**Error: MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: Already connected**

MqttHandler.java

```
public class MqttHandler {

    private MqttClient client;

    public void connect(String brokerUrl, String clientId) {
        try {
            // Set up the persistence layer
            MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

            // Initialize the MQTT client
            client = new MqttClient(brokerUrl, clientId, persistence);

            // Set up the connection options
            MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connectOptions.setCleanSession(true);

            // Connect to the broker
            client.connect(connectOptions);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void publish(String topic, String message) {
        try {
            MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage(message.getBytes());
            client.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void subscribe(String topic) {
        try {
            client.subscribe(topic);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with over way to setup the connection as well -

```
        val credentials: AWSCredentials = BasicAWSCredentials(connection.credentials.accessKeyId,
            connection.credentials.secretAccessKey)

        val credentialsProvider = object : AWSCredentialsProvider {
            override fun getCredentials(): AWSCredentials {
                return BasicAWSCredentials(connection.credentials.accessKeyId,
                    connection.credentials.secretAccessKey)
            }

            override fun refresh() {
                // No need to implement refresh for temporary credentials
            }
        }

        val mqttManager = AWSIotMqttManager(clientID,"${connection.credentials.IoTHostEndPoint}")

        mqttManager.connect(credentialsProvider, AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback { status, throwable ->
            Timber.d("mqttManager.connect IN status $status")
            if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connected) {
                Timber.d("mqttManager.connect IN status $status")
                // Successfully connected to AWS IoT
                // Now you can publish messages or subscribe to topics
            } else {
                // Handle connection failure
                throwable?.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
```

There I was getting diffrent error -

**Error: MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade.**

Please help me setup the connection with MQTT on android. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: are you using the correct endpoint, I believe wss endpoint is different, you can see that from IoT core panel at endpoints section

Comment: yes the end point is correct because a connection is being stablish from node js without any issue.